# Hadoop makes only one output file even when I set numReducetasks to 2

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have setup hadoop on ubuntu in pseudo distributed mode. My understanding is that I can run a job with more than one reducer in pseudo mode. But even after setting numReducetasks to 2, I am getting only one output file as partr0000. why is it ?

Note: My input file has only 12 records. It is a secondary sort MR program.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set no. of reducers through numReducetasks, it is just a hint to the framework. I doesn't guarantee that you'll get only the specified no. of reducers as it actually depends on the no. of partitions you get after the map phase. And based on the no. of partitions you'll get the no. of reducers. Partitioning happens based on keys and the default partitioner is hash partitioner. So the keys are hashed based on a hash function and clubbed into groups. When you talk about so small data all the keys go to the same partition, as the framework tries its best to make the processing as efficient as possible and creating multiple partitions for such a small data would be an overkil.

Comment: It is just the other way round. Based in number of reducers the number of partitions are decided.If you see the `getPartition()` : public int getPartition(K key, V value,
                          int numReduceTasks) {
    return (key.hashCode() & Integer.MAX_VALUE) % numReduceTasks;
  }

Comment: Hence, it is not a hint to the framework. IMHO you can always set number of reducers to whatever you want, it is just with the case of mappers that with `mapred.map.tasks` what you can set is just indicative to the system and it decides on the basis of the number of input splits. But with number of reducers, that's not the case.

Comment: Thank you so much for the correction. Seems I have to do dig the resource, which I had used, once again. There was not much into 3 yrs ago and I was very confident about the resources which I was using to study about Hadoop at that time. Apologies Rob for conveying the wrong info. 1 downvote from my side.

Comment: I agree Amar. Thank you so very much. I found the same when I looked at the source, and trust me it's really embarrassing to give a wrong answer with so much confidence. Thanks a tonne!

Comment: @Rob : I'm really sorry for the wrong answer. Bunch of apologies from my side.

Comment: It happens man. no issues. Rob will understand. I have added an answer hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

If you see the `getPartition()` of the default partiotioner, `HashPartitioner`, it looks like as folllows:

```
public int getPartition(K key, V value, int numReduceTasks) { 
    return (key.hashCode() & Integer.MAX_VALUE) % numReduceTasks; 
}
```

I think here it is happening just **by chance** that all the records are falling under the same partition. Just run a test and see what values you get for the above function with your 12 records.

And number of reducers and number of output files need not be always same, as there might be no output records from some reducers (even though it received some inputs).

Also checkout the hadoop UI from your browser when you run this job, you should see total number of reducers to the number you have set.
Check your `conf/mapred-site.xml` and their you can find the URL to hit for seeing the Hadoop UI :

```
<property>
  <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
  <value>localhost:54311</value>
  <description>The host and port that the MapReduce job tracker runs
  at.  If "local", then jobs are run in-process as a single map
  and reduce task.
  </description>
</property>
```

So, if you hit `localhost:54311` , you should see the running jobs list.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because of number of records. Hadoop takes 64 MB of data for each cluster by default since your data is less than 1 block it is not divided into multiple blocks.

Comment: Thanks for smttsp and Tariq.